# How can I get the Ignore Pattern in TortoiseSVN (v1.6.13) to work properly with Visual Studio (C#) files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ignore

Using the UI I have set my Global Ignore Pattern to

```
*.suo *.user *.ReSharper.* *ReSharper* *.5.1.ReSharper.user bin Bin obj 
Obj Debug Release
```

but it doesn't appear to do anything.

All *.user and *.suo files show up with the blue question mark overlay.  If I right-click the file and click TortoiseSVN | Add to ignore list | *.user, then yes, the files are ignored, but only for the folder where I make the change.

I even tried editing the AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config file (you can pull it up by clicking the "Edit" button in the Settings window) with the following line (line wrap included for clarity):

```
global-ignores = *.suo *.user *.ReSharper.* *ReSharper* *.5.1.ReSharper.user 
bin Bin obj Obj Debug Release
```

but I haven't had any luck.

And yes, I have rebooted several times.

Has anyone out there experienced this same problem and found a solution to the issue?  Is there something glaring that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried doing a SVN -> Cleanup after you set the ignore filters?

Comment: Don't put things in global-ignore use the svn:ignore property instead.

Comment: OK - The "SVN clean up" seemed to help a lot.  Also, we had many cases where bin and obj folders were checked in even though the folders were empty.  Deleting the empty folders fixed the rest of my problem.

Answer (score 3):

svn:Ignore property only works on files that are not versioned.

If the files you want to ignore are in the repository, you will have to delete them, and only then, will they be ignored.

[svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)

Comment: The files I am referring to are not versioned.  I don't want them to show up when I am checking in files because there are hundreds of them and they make it difficult to find files that I need to add.

Comment: Ignored files will still be visible, but will be gray instead of blue. If you added a directory using the ide, I believe that all to files in this directory are automaticely added, so it won't take the ignore pattern. I would suggest going to the command line and make a `svn status` to see which directory are added. If the files you want ignored are added, you could `svn revert` them. From there, they would be ignored. Hope this help.